# Do most distant objects on the Hubble diagram 'tell' as the Hubble constant has been valid for at least 60 million years?

Tags: speed-of-light, astronomy, space-expansion, distance

As we all know the deeper we look into the space the further we look into the past... So if the Hubble diagram shows the most distant objects at a 20 Mpsec or ~60Mly distance from us (and as for not so large distances where the expansion of the space does not considerably affect the time the light travel to us) we can assume that those objects are measured to have been moving according to the Hubble constant 60 million years ago as we see them aproximately 60 million years in the past... So if it is like so the Hubble constant has not changed for at least 60 million years. Can we then pressume that the Universe has been expanding at the nearly same rate for the past 60 million jears? Why then some people tell us the universe is expanding with acceleration? [image]

Comment: Why did you chose this particular dataset? It only shows our nearest cosmic neighborhood. The residual motion of these nearby objects is far larger than any possible acceleration effect suggested by more recent measurements and the statistics is completely insufficient to make a precision estimate.

Answer (score 1):

60 million years is a short time in cosmological terms. The Hubble parameter indeed hasn't changed much in that time.

Also, an unchanging Hubble parameter doesn't mean the expansion isn't accelerating. If $H$ is constant, then as comoving objects move away from us they pick up speed ($d$ increases so $Hd$ increases), which means they're accelerating away from us. For the expansion not to accelerate, $H$ has to drop with time.

Comment: In particular, acceleration is $\ddot{a}=\frac{d}{dt}(Ha)$, which isn't proportional to $\dot{H}$.

Comment: But are we told that space is expanding like a 'baking bread'  so there is space as energy carrier although we do not know how actually it is growing, expanding or increasing its volume but it seams logical that it is the cause of astrophysical objects moving away from each other..and that these velocities need to increase with distance... . But is it also logical that if we spot an object in future that is identically distant from Earth as some present object and that receding velocities from Earth are same in that particular point that in that case the expansion of Universe is constant?